# sqlite3 задание Найдите два потока с самыми низкими значениями успеваемости. В отчет выведите номер потока, название курса, фамилию и имя преподавател

Tags: sqlite3

Найдите два потока с самыми низкими значениями успеваемости. В отчет выведите номер потока, название курса, фамилию и имя преподавателя (одним столбцом), оценку успеваемости.

Неверное решение:

SELECT grade, (SELECT number_stream FROM streams WHERE id= stream_id) AS number_stream, (SELECT name FROM courses WHERE (SELECT id FROM streams)) AS course_name, (SELECT name || surname FROM teachers WHERE id=teacher_id) AS teacher_name FROM grades ORDER BY grade LIMIT 2;

Ошибка в части (SELECT name FROM courses WHERE (SELECT id FROM streams)) - такая конструкция работать не будет.

Прошу подсказать верное решение.

Comment: 1. Оформите свой код в соответствующий тег. 2. Почитайте про вложенные запросы - у вас ошибка скрипта связана именно с ними. Вы не передаете никакие параметры во вложенные запросы, а если и передаете, то непонятно какие. 3. "Ошибка в части... такая конструкция работать не будет" - обычно после where указывают поле/набор для сравнения значений, затем знак/операция сравнения и, в конце концов второе значение. В вашем случае после where только 1 набор, который ни с чем не сравнивается. 4. Здесь могут только направить к верному решению - про "подсказывать" это к соседу по парте.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT performance
   ...> 'grade',
   ...> (SELECT name FROM courses WHERE id = stream_id) AS course_name,
   ...> (SELECT name || surname FROM teachers WHERE id = teacher_id) AS teacher_name,
   ...> (SELECT number FROM training_groups WHERE id = stream_id) AS number_stream
   ...> FROM grades ORDER BY performance LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]